# Angular Directive call multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-directive

tree-view.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of nodes; let i=index" class="parent" [id]="item.name" appTreeView>
        {{item.name}}
        <div class="child" *ngIf="item.child">
            <app-tree-view [nodes]="item.child"></app-tree-view>  // recursive call 
        </div>
</div>
```

treeview.ts

```
this.data=[
      {
        name:"level 1",
        child:[
          {
            name:"level 1.1",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name:"level 2",
        child:[
          {
            name:"level 2.1",
            child:[
              {
                name:"level 2.1.1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener,Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTreeView]',
})
export class TreeViewDirective {

  constructor(private render:Renderer2) { }
  @HostListener('click',['$event'])
  check(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);
    const avalclass:string=event.target.classList.value;
    if(avalclass.includes('expand')){
      this.render.removeClass(event.target,'expand');
    }else{
      this.render.addClass(event.target,'expand');
    }
    
  }
}
```

Output

- Level 1
- Level 2

If I click level 2 expand sub menu level 2.1
**console print one time**

- Level 1
- Level 2

  - Level 2.1

then i click level 2.1 expand sub menu 2.1.1
***console print two times***

- Level 1
- Level 2

  - Level 2.1

    - Level 2.1.1

*Why console print multiple times. what is my mistakes*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console prints multiple times the same because of **you are using recursion to call a parent and his descendants**. *You are binding a click event multiple times* depending on what level is the element where you're clicking on. If you are aware of the flow of your code:

- If you click in a first level item (Level 1 or Level 2): it prints one time.
- If you click in a second level item (Level 1.1 or Level 2.2): it prints two times, one for the second level and other for the first one.
- And so on..

I've prepared a demo with the code that you put in your question. You can see in the console who is calling the event and who is the host element each time.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recursion-directives?file=src/app/tree-view.directive.ts

You could solve that adding a flag to your directive and checking it in your check function:

```
if (this.isFired) {
      return;
    }
this.isFired = true;
```

Or comparing the current host element and the element that triggered the event:

```
if(this.el.nativeElement.id == event.target.id){
   console.log("click on: " + event.target.id);
      const avalclass: string = event.target.classList.value;

      if (avalclass.includes("expand")) {
        this.render.removeClass(event.target, "expand");
      } else {
        this.render.addClass(event.target, "expand");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i'm binding multiple time using recursive function so how can i solve this issue.